# How to add custom typings definitions?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a global function `window["__log"] = something()` and I just want VSCode to stop bugging with errors about it (:

I added reference to my main ts file and created simple definition:

```
///<reference path="./core/utilities/logger/logger.d.ts"/>

// logger.d.ts
export declare function __log(...values: any) {}
```

but I'm getting an error:

> An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.

I never wrote typing definitions before, and google isn't helping... How can I make this work?

Comment: I don't think you need to use the declare keyword in a .d.ts file

Comment: Nothing changes when I remove it... Still getting `~ ambient context` and `Cannot find name '__log'.` errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
// in someDefinitionFile.d.ts
declare function __log(message:string): void;
```

usage:

```
/// <reference path="someDefinitionFile.d.ts" />
__log("My fancy message!");
```

The error you got is due to the `{ }` in the d.ts file.